# What is the equivalent of NSLineBreakMode in iOS 7 attributed strings drawing methods?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uikit, nsattributedstring

There was a method

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode alignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment;
```

which I must replace now for iOS 7. I get as far as

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
[self drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```

but how to specify the line break mode like word wrap? I searched documentation of Attributed string drawing symbols but no mention of line break mode. Is this automartically always word-wrap?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to create a paragraph style.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style};
[self drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```

More information here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle?language=objc

Comment: I think you can also use `[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init]` instead of the mutable copy.

Comment: @zavié mutableCopy was used because he wanted to instantiate a NSMutableParagraphStyle based on defaultParagraphStyle. If you init it as NSMutableParagraphStyle.default it turns into a NSParagraphStyle instead. So you have to turn it into a mutable by calling mutableCopy.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 5:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
   .font: font,
   .paragraphStyle: style
]
```