# UITextField inside UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

Is there a way to attach a UITextField inside inside the range of an NSAttributedString that is inside a UITextView?

I want to recreate something like this:

[image]

Where the user would be able to press the empty lines to type text.

Comment: Looks to me like a `UIStackView` made up of 8 panels of a custom `UIView` / `UITextView` subclass

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a frame for the `UITextField` like so:

```
- (CGRect)textFieldFrameForCharacterRange:(NSRange)charRange inTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSRange glyphRange = [textView.layoutManager glyphRangeForCharacterRange:charRange actualCharacterRange:NULL];
    CGRect boundingRect = [textView.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:textView.textContainer];
    return boundingRect;
}
```

and then add it as a subview of the `UITextView`. Determining a character range to pass to the above method can be easy too - just search for a run of underlines, or maybe a custom attribute using `- enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:`.

The catch is this won't work properly if the underlines are split into more than one line, but `UITextField` wouldn't fit that case anyway. So you need a way to make sure the underline remains unbroken. The U+2060 unicode character may help, see [Prevent line break in a NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489781/prevent-line-break-in-a-nsattributedstring) for more. An `NSTextAttachment` with the underline represented as an image would also be guaranteed not to get word wrapped.

Alternatively, you could implement a `UITextViewDelegate`, or possibly even a `UITextView` subclass, that disallows selection and editing outside of the underline ranges. That way you can avoid the weirdness of `UITextField`s within `UITextView`s. But the drawback with this method is even if you deleted an underline character every time the user types a character, the user would still see the overall length of the underline fluctuating slightly.