# CGSize sizeSpace = [@" " sizeWithFont:self.fontHashtag constrainedToSize:rect.size lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

```
CGSize sizeSpace = [@" " sizeWithFont:self.fontHashtag constrainedToSize:rect.size lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
```

How to remove `deprecated` warning from code ?

I'm a fresher so can you please explain elaborately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeWithFont` is `depreciated` so you need to use `sizeWithAttributes` method.

```
CGSize sizeSpace = [@" " sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.fontHashtag}];
```

Comment: Thank you It worked

Comment: Welcome mate. You can check here for other [attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197903) Happy Coding :)